# Linux Mint не может совершить сопряжение с Bluetooth-наушниками

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth

Установил Linux Mint 20.3 Una и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, связанной с Bluetooth. Адаптер работает исправно, я могу связать компьютер с телефоном и со старыми Bluetooth-наушниками, но не могу сделать это с новыми, при этом они могут подключиться к телефону и другому компьютеру на базе Windows 10. Пробовал все возможные комбинации перезагрузки наушников, Bluetooth, адаптера, компьютера - всё без толку.

При попытке совершить спряжение в Blueman появляется ошибка "Pairing failed for: Redmi AirDots 3 (MAC-адрес)"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке подключения в Blueman предлагается ввести ПИН-код. Какой бы стандартный ПИН-код я не вводил (на старых наушниках сработал ПИН-код 0000), вылезает ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке совершить спряжение в консоли появляется ошибка "Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationRejected"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрепляю ссылку на текстовый файл в GitHub, в котором содержится потенциально полезная информация о системе: [вывод консоли.txt](https://github.com/koldunblshamanbl/koldunblshamanbl.github.io/blob/main/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8.txt)

Я в отчаянии. Учитывая все вышесказанное, проблем нет ни с наушниками, ни с адаптером, но всё же соединение установить невозможно. Прошу о помощи любого, кто может решить эту проблему.

Comment: с такими вопросами вам скорее на https://askubuntu.com/ или подобные

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на указанном Сергеем Татаринчевым сайте. Решения, как оказалось, [нет](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356008/marley-exodus-anc-bluetooth-headphone-wont-pair-in-21-04) (Marley Exodus ANC Bluetooth headphone won't pair in 21.04 - Ask Ubuntu). Автор того вопроса опытным путём выяснил, что на Ubuntu Bluetooth-адаптеры работают далеко не со всеми наушниками и что это нельзя исправить никаким путём. Если повезёт, то ваши наушники будут сочетаться с имеющимся Bluetooth-адаптером, а если нет, то придётся искать другой (либо же пользоваться Windows, на котором подобные проблемы не возникают).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)